# Move a div along a curvy path on scroll

Tags: jquery, path, scroll

I have made a path using an array [x,y,deg]. I need to move a div along this path, which is a curvy path with lots of zigzagging over the page vertically. I need the div to follow the path when the page is scrolled.

Comment: Something like this: http://joelb.me/scrollpath/ ?

Comment: Yeah almost like that. But in my case the div has to scroll down with the window scroller (in my case i am using nicescroll) i tried it with $(divid).css({left,top}); but it doesnt reach the end of the path, my total height of the path is 8000 and the total height of the page is around 10000px. i need to find a math with which the div   scrolls up and down with the window scroll bar smoothly.